# How can Send Notification to IOS in Tamil Language Using C#

Tags: c#, ios

I'm developing an application using C# which have to send notification to both iOS and Android.In Android notification send in Tamil. But send a notification to iOS in English it working good. But, how can I send other languages like Hindi, French, German and so on.

Below is the code which I used:

```
string devicetocken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";//  iphone device token
int port = 2195;
String hostname = "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com";
string certificatePath = @"Certificates.pfx";
string certificatePassword = "";
X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(certificatePath, certificatePassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
X509Certificate2Collection certificatesCollection = new X509Certificate2Collection(clientCertificate);

TcpClient client = new TcpClient(hostname, port);
SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(),false,new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate),null);
try
{
    sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostname, certificatesCollection, SslProtocols.Default, false);
}
catch (AuthenticationException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Authentication failed");
    client.Close();
    return;
}
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream);
writer.Write((byte)0);  //The command
writer.Write((byte)0);  //The first byte of the deviceId length (big-endian first byte)
writer.Write((byte)32); //The deviceId length (big-endian second byte)
int len = devicetocken.Length;
int len_half = len / 2;
byte[] bs = new byte[len_half];
for (int i = 0; i != len_half; i++)
{
    bs[i] = (byte)Int32.Parse(devicetocken.Substring(i * 2, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
}
byte[] b0 = bs;
writer.Write(b0);
String payload;
string strmsgbody = "";
strmsgbody = "சென்னை";
//strmsgbody = "Chennai";
Debug.WriteLine("during testing via device!");
payload = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"" + strmsgbody + "\",\"sound\":\"mailsent.wav\"},\"acme1\":\"bar\",\"acme2\":42}";
writer.Write((byte)0); //First byte of payload length; (big-endian first byte)
writer.Write((byte)payload.Length);     //payload length (big-endian second byte)
byte[] b1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload);
writer.Write(b1);
writer.Flush();
byte[] array = memoryStream.ToArray();
Debug.WriteLine("This is being sent...\n\n");
Debug.WriteLine(array);
try
{
    sslStream.Write(array);
    sslStream.Flush();
}
catch
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Write failed buddy!!");
}

client.Close();
Debug.WriteLine("Client closed.");
```

Comment: Finally found a solution by using PushSharp.

Comment: Please post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You do not say what the problem is - you do not say what happens when you send the message. **Since you have not asked a question, nobody will be able to help you.**

However, a quick glance at the code shows:

1. You are assuming that the payload will never be more than 255 characters long (you are setting the high byte of the length to 0).
2. You are making the payload length the number of Unicode characters, not the number of characters in the UTF-8 representation of the payload. Is this correct? It sounds unlikely. I don't know the answer, but you should.

Comment: Hi nugae, Am asked my question like how to send push notification to IOS mobile.. The above code working for english, but i want to send it in other languages,.